# Conversion of yes/no items to Likert scale items

Tags: binary-data, likert, scales

I constructed a Likert scale but unfortunately it had some yes/no items. As a result I have to revise it.  Can those yes/no items be re-worded as Likert scale items and would this be considered valid?

Comment: This will depend entirely on the question; some yes/no questions can be turned into Likert type questions, some can't. Also, why do you have to revise the scale? There is no necessity for a scale to include only Likert type questions.